# Android Layout files in eclipse is not showing the real layout design

Tags: android, xml, layout, screen

Android screen design in eclipse Layout files doesn't appear like the way it appears on devices or emulator. When I designed the layout first time it was working will but suddenly all layouts has damaged on eclipse but not on real phones and emulator

The damaged design:

[image]
[image]

How it shown on phone:

[image]
[image]

so does anybody experienced this situation?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't show the layout really well. Especially, the colors look wrong.

Comment: I restarted eclipse many times nothing changed

Comment: Restarting eclipse is not enough, it must restart adb also ... It solved the problem thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpK almost answered the question.

Anyone faces this problem can exit eclipse and from task manager try to find adb task under processes tab then end this task. Then open eclipse again; It worked with me.

Answer (score 1):

Hey are you using Absolute or Relative Layout, then try to use LinearLayout.

Comment: I am using RelativeLayout which is sometimes makes a problem but not like what Happend above.

Comment: Ok.. Try using LinearLayout. You could use Relative only if you want to place one widget on another, if there is no such need then it is safe to use Linear. In relative all widgets are related to eachother, so some resolution problems can occur.

Answer (score 1):

It happened many times for me. In that time, i just restart my eclipse otherwise, remove the project from workspace then, restore it from local history. This will give the solution. Try these ways.

Hope this helps you.